# Impala query for yesterdays data without typing date possibly using python

Tags: python, sql, hadoop, impala

The data is already parsed like date time '2018-03-08 00:00:00'.  I can get the data for 3/8/18 by saying where BETWEEN '2018-03-08 00:00:00' and '2018-03-08 24:00:00'.  But I would like to use an Impala date time function somehow so that I can run this daily without having manually type in each date.  I have read through some of the documentation but am still confused.

## Query Impala

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sourceaddress,count(sourceaddress) as count FROM table
GROUP BY sourceaddress
ORDER BY count desc
LIMIT 10")
```

Even if I can define yesterday in python before the query like:

```
yesterday = str((pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.Timedelta(days=1)).date())
```

and somehow incorporate it into an Impala query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was not completely clear, but from what I understand you want to use Impala/python Date Time functions to automate your query to select one day worth of data. Below are my examples of how you can do in impala.

```
-- to_date - function will cut the date from timestamp
-- now()   - gives you the current timestamp

select to_date(now()) as currentDate, 
to_date(now() + interval 1 days) as currentDatePlusaDay, 
now() as currentTimestamp, 
now() + interval 1 day as currentTimestampPlusaDay, 
concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), ' 00:00:00') as whereBetweenMin, 
concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), ' 24:00:00') as whereBetweenMax ;

--Result

+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| currentdate | currentdateplusaday | currenttimestamp              | currenttimestampplusaday      | wherebetweenmin     | wherebetweenmax     |
+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-03-23  | 2018-03-24          | 2018-03-23 12:14:36.073281000 | 2018-03-24 12:14:36.073281000 | 2018-03-22 00:00:00 | 2018-03-22 24:00:00 |
+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

--You can probably use wherebetweenmin & wherebetweenmax
```

Comment: select substring(time,1,10) as dateString, substring(time,12,2) as hourString, count(*) as countString 
from table
where time BETWEEN concat(to_date(now() - interval 5 days), " 00:00:00") and concat(to_date(now() - interval 5 days), " 24:00:00") 
group by substring(time,1,10), substring(time,12,2) 
order by 1,2     @roh

Comment: @sectechguy if this answer is the solution to your problem then you should accept it.